# T5 Heathrow International Connections

Tags: short-connections, lhr

If the long-haul British Airways international arrival gate is in Heathrow Terminal 5C (T5C), and the long-haul departure is from Terminal 5B (T5B), is there a way to avoid going through huge crowds at Terminal 5A (T5A)? Arrival to departure time-gap is 3 hours.

And is it possible to do this from T5B arrival to T5B departure, without going to T5A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the detailed info on FlyerTalk [here](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1549278-lhr-terminal-5c-flights-connections-pictorial-guide.html), [here](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1735255-guide-connecting-lhr-t5.html#post25935779) and [here](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1572418-lhr-terminal-5b-flight-connections-pictorial-guide-including-t5b-bus-service.html) you can most definitely do:

- T5B -> T5B
- T5C -> T5C
- T5B -> T5C
- T5C -> T5B

without going through T5A: there are security checkpoints in T5B and T5C, but note **you can only use them once the gate for your onward flight is known (and is one of those terminals)**, which in the case of a 3-hour layover may mean you have to wait a bit or go through T5A.

As explained in the last post, it’s slightly more complex for T5C -> T5B: take the people mover towards T5A, but stop at T5B, and go up to the security check.

Note that there are separate departures (post security) and arrivals (pre security) walkways between the terminals, and the people mover is only for departures (post security) in the ABC direction and only for arrivals (pre security) in the other. That means that for T5B -> T5C it's the opposite: you clear security in T5B first, then take the people mover to T5C.

Just follow the signs and you should be fine.

Comment: found another link with different set of flyer talk pictures  [link] (https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1572418-lhr-terminal-5b-flight-connections-pictorial-guide-including-t5b-bus-service.html)

Comment: @abcihep Edited the answer to include that link and make it clear that T5C -> T5B is indeed possible.

Answer (score 2):

I just was there yesterday, so I can provide current information :-)

> is there a way to avoid going through huge crowds at Terminal 5A (T5A)?

There is a train connecting T5C->T5B->T5A. So follow the signs to Gate B and gate A, hop on the train and than get off at the first stop (B32-B48). The train can be crowded. However, that depends a bit where you get funneled through security.

> Arrival to departure time-gap is 3 hours.

That is more than enough.

> And is it possible to do this from T5B arrival to T5B departure, without going to T5A?

Yes, but it depends on where you will be funneled through security and if your departure gate is know at arrival time. Unfortunately LHR requires transit security for everyone (which is bit of a pain) and they can be annoyingly late at announcing gates. We had an 19:05 departure with a gate announcement time of 17:50. Turns out we were in T5A and our gate was in T5C. It took us maybe 15 minutes to get there: the crowds were fine but the train was full and doesn't go all that often.